# matplotlib-cpp with Visual Studio Using C++ (especially 3D plots)?

Tags: python, c++, matplotlib, plot, visual-studio-2015

I have been lately using c++ for some of my development work. My current work demands for some 3D plots similar to the one used in Python matplotlib. Fortunately, I found this wrapper -> [matplotlib-cpp](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp) 
Now, I am a noob and not good with CMAKE and make files(finding slightly difficult in setting it up). So my question is:

I am using Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.8), how should I build and set up the [matplotlib-cpp](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp)  in an empty Visual Studio solution and make the plots work?

It might sound basic, but would be a great help for people like me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using a package manager like `vcpkg` to get a built version of `matplotlib-cpp` with all the necessary dependencies. Read [vcpkg quick start guide](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#quick-start) to do that. Also you would not need to 'set up' Visual Studio project header paths, library directories etc. vcpkg will hook them up for you if you choose to integrate vcpkg with Visual Studio. If not, you can always install the packages on a project-by-project basis using NuGet.